# Input video into program rather than live stream video using camera

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, pytorch, torchvision

I have a python program which uses image processing to detect cracks using a camera to live stream a video.

Is there a way, rather than live streaming using a camera, to instead upload a video taken, into the program and process it this way instead ?

I have attached my code below to have a look at:

```
#import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
from threading import Thread
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from segment.predict import run

# Define VideoStream class to handle streaming of video from webcam in separate processing thread
# Source - Adrian Rosebrock, PyImageSearch: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/28/increasing-raspberry-pi-fps-with-python-and-opencv/


class VideoStream:
    """Camera object that controls video streaming from the Picamera"""

    def __init__(self, resolution=(640, 480), framerate=30):
        # Initialize the PiCamera and the camera image stream
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret = self.stream.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC,
                              cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'))
        ret = self.stream.set(3, resolution[0])
        ret = self.stream.set(4, resolution[1])

        # Read first frame from the stream
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

        # Variable to control when the camera is stopped
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        # Start the thread that reads frames from the video stream
        Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        # Keep looping indefinitely until the thread is stopped
        while True:
            # If the camera is stopped, stop the thread
            if self.stopped:
                # Close camera resources
                self.stream.release()
                return

            # Otherwise, grab the next frame from the stream
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def read(self):
        # Return the most recent frame
        return self.frame

    def stop(self):
        # Indicate that the camera and thread should be stopped
        self.stopped = True


# image_path = "test2.jpg"
# model_path = "model.tflite"

# interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
# interpreter.allocate_tensors()
# input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
# output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
# input_shape = input_details[0]['shape']

# Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()

# Initialize video stream
videostream = VideoStream(resolution=(640, 480), framerate=30).start()
time.sleep(1)

model = torch.load('best.pt')['model'].float()  # load to FP32
model.eval()
while True:
    print("New Frame")
    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    frame1 = videostream.read()
    image = frame1.copy()
    cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", frame1)
    disp_image, det = run(weights='best.pt', source='frame.jpg', device='cpu', exist_ok=True)
    detection = det.item()
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    cv2timestr = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    ratio = 0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if detection == 0:
        cv2.putText(disp_image, cv2timestr, (30, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(disp_image, 'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(
            frame_rate_calc), (30, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(disp_image, 'No Crack Detected', (30, 90),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    else:

        cv2.putText(disp_image, cv2timestr, (30, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(disp_image, 'FPS: {0:.2f}'.format(
            frame_rate_calc), (30, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.putText(disp_image, 'Crack Detected', (30, 80),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imwrite("cracks/crack" + timestr + ".jpg", disp_image)

    cv2.namedWindow('Crack detector', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('Crack detector', disp_image)

    # Calculate framerate
    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2 - t1) / freq
    frame_rate_calc = 1 / time1
    # break
    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Clean up
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
videostream.stop()
```

I’m not sure which part of the code needs changing. Would it just be as simple as reading the video file and then running the remaining code while removing the video stream class? would it process the video like this ?

Comment: You can simply use the `cv2.videoCapture` object to read video from a file. The major change is that you don't want a thread continually buffering the most recent frame (this has meaning when processing a live stream but not in the case when all frames are available from the start).